# Multiple use of LEFT JOIN brings only 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

It is an intelligent tag base image search system. User adds images with its proper tags in such a table:

```
image (id, title, ...)
tag (id, title) /* It doesn't matter who has created the tag*/
imagetag (image_id, tag_id) /* One image may have multiple tags */
```

User views images and the **visits from **those images' tags**** are logged in `usertagview` table. (Note that I've used an `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` query for that purpose.)

```
usertagview (user_id, tag_id, view_count)
```

---

Now please consider some images with the following tags:

- `river`,  `day` (It's a picture that shows a river in a sunny day)
- `river`,  `night` (That river at the light of the midnight moon)
- `tree`, `day`
- `tree`, `night`
- `flower`, `day`
- `flower`, `night`

User searches for the tag `river` and any images that has the tag **river** is displayed: In this case the first image (tagged by **river day**) and the second (tagged by **river night**) are shown. User **views** the second image (tagged by `river` and `night`) and view it is logged in the table `usertagview`.

Then the user tries a new search for the tag `tree` and views the `tree night` image.

I want that if the user searches for `flower`, the `flower night` be preferred over the `flower day`. I mean `flower night` should come before `flower day`. In other words I want a query that lists images tagged by `flower` according to user's previous views. (**`flower night` first, OTHER `flower`s next**).

My query that was failed:

```
SELECT

    DISTINCT (image.id) AS image_id,
    image.title AS image_title,
    SUM(usertagview.view_count) AS SUM_of_all_tag_views_for_each_image

FROM (image)

JOIN imagetag ON imagetag.image_id = image.id

**LEFT JOIN** usertagview ON
    usertagview.tag_id = imagetag.tag_id
    AND usertagview.user_id = {$user_id_from_php}

WHERE

    imagetag.tag_id IN ( {impolde(',', $array_of_id_of_tags_that_the_user_has_entered)} )
    AND
    usertagview.tag_id IN
        (SELECT tag_id FROM imagetag WHERE userimagetag.image_id = image.id)

ORDER BY SUM_of_all_tag_views_for_each_image DESC
```

#### THE PROBLEM

is that the **`**LEFT JOIN**`** in my query has no difference with a normal **`INNER JOIN`**. They both have the same result. Even if I use **`RIGHT JOIN`** it will have no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that your `left join` is behaving the same as an `inner join` is because you have additional criteria for your `left join` in your `where` clause.  This essentially turns your `outer join` into an `inner join`.

The reason for this is because if `usertagview.tag_id` is `NULL` in the case where there is no matching record, your `IN` statement in your `WHERE` clause eliminates the row with the `NULL` value.

To correct this, you could move your `usertagview.tag_id IN ...` check into your join's `ON` clause.

However, this is only half of your problem.  You're only checking the views for the specific tag that was entered by the user, but if I understand your actual requirements, you want to check the views for any tags that are associated with any image that has a tag that matches your search term.

For example, when the user enters `flower`, you want to first find any image that is tagged with `flower`, and then check the views for all other tags for that set of images.

I believe the following query accomplishes this, and [this SQL Fiddle shows the query in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95a69/9):

```
SELECT
  i.id AS image_id,
  i.title AS image_title,
  IFNULL(SUM(utv.view_count), 0) AS associated_view_totals
FROM
  imagetag originalTag
  JOIN imagetag associatedTags 
    ON associatedTags.image_id = originalTag.image_id
  JOIN image i 
    ON i.id = associatedTags.image_id
  LEFT JOIN usertagview utv 
    ON utv.user_id = 1
    AND utv.tag_id = associatedTags.tag_id
WHERE
  -- User searches for flower tag (Let's assume 5 == flower)...
  originalTag.tag_id IN (5)
GROUP BY
  i.id,
  i.title
ORDER BY 
  associated_view_totals DESC
```

Comment: Perfect. It works like a charm now. Also the sqlfiddle really helped cause I had to change it a bit! I'd really needed the function `IFNULL` and I believe I should learn more about advanced queries abilities like that you have used `imagetag` two times. Any website/PDF for teaching advanced querying? It would really help me. Because I haven't yet deeply understand the logic that you have uses in the query. I would more appreciate any advanced mysql query tutorial or PDF. Thank you

Comment: @smhnaji I think you're already on the right track...  In your query you were correctly using inner joins vs outer joins.  The only tricky part in this query is that you join to the same table twice, which is something people forget is possible.  As far as a good reference, the [MySQL documentation is actually very helpful](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/functions.html), and provides good examples as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem.  And fortunately, an easy one to solve.

See this?

```
LEFT JOIN usertagview ON
    usertagview.tag_id = imagetag.tag_id -- see this?
    AND usertagview.user_id = {$user_id_from_php}  

WHERE

    imagetag.tag_id IN ( {impolde(',', $array_of_id_of_tags_that_the_user_has_entered)} )
    AND
```

And this?

```
    usertagview.tag_id IN -- and this?
        (SELECT tag_id FROM imagetag WHERE userimagetag.image_id = image.id)
```

Both conditions share the same field, i.e. `usertagview.tag_id`.
So that `usertagview.tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM ...)` on your WHERE clause basically cancels out whatever success usertagview on `LEFT JOIN`ing the imagetag had.

So to fix your query, restore your `INNER JOIN`-y usertagview to a `LEFT JOIN` one, then move usertagview condition to JOIN condition instead:

```
SELECT

    DISTINCT (image.id) AS image_id,
    image.title AS image_title,
    SUM(usertagview.view_count) AS SUM_of_all_tag_views_for_each_image

FROM (image)

JOIN imagetag ON imagetag.image_id = image.id

LEFT JOIN usertagview ON
    usertagview.tag_id = imagetag.tag_id
    AND usertagview.user_id = {$user_id_from_php}

    -- moved the WHERE condition here
    AND
    usertagview.tag_id IN
        (SELECT tag_id FROM imagetag WHERE userimagetag.image_id = image.id)


WHERE

    imagetag.tag_id IN ( {impolde(',', $array_of_id_of_tags_that_the_user_has_entered)} )

ORDER BY SUM_of_all_tag_views_for_each_image DESC
```

That would fix it. If it isn't (as I don't know exactly on your tables which are one-to-many to each other, or one-to-one to each other, so in this case I'll just throw what would *usually* works), try to change the `INNER JOIN imagetag` to `LEFT JOIN`. And since the `imagetag` condition in WHERE clause will cancel out whatever rows that results from `LEFT JOIN` condition had, move that `imagetag` condition from `WHERE` clause to `LEFT JOIN` as well :

```
SELECT

    DISTINCT (image.id) AS image_id,
    image.title AS image_title,
    SUM(usertagview.view_count) AS SUM_of_all_tag_views_for_each_image

FROM (image)

LEFT JOIN imagetag ON imagetag.image_id = image.id
    -- WHERE clause condition moved here.
    -- WHERE conditionXXX basically cancels out whatever rows
    -- obtained from `LEFT JOIN ON conditionXXX`, in which conditionXXX share
    -- the same field.  IN this case, it is imagetag.
    AND    
    imagetag.tag_id IN ( {impolde(',', $array_of_id_of_tags_that_the_user_has_entered)} )


LEFT JOIN usertagview ON
    usertagview.tag_id = imagetag.tag_id
    AND usertagview.user_id = {$user_id_from_php}

 -- moved here
    AND
    usertagview.tag_id IN
        (SELECT tag_id FROM imagetag WHERE userimagetag.image_id = image.id)



ORDER BY SUM_of_all_tag_views_for_each_image DESC
```

And if the second suggestion still doesn't deliver the results, your query is currently handling **multiple** one-to-many table relationships. SQL can't figure out your intent if you have multiple one-to-many table relations in queries; in this case, you need to flatten out the results to get the correct output. Here's a good walkthrough on how to flatten out results: http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/sql-count-computer-program-does-what.html

Answer (score 1):

You always get the results of your table image + INNER JOIN imagetag, regardsless what you join next/after. If you want more results you need to LEFT JOIN imagetag table as well then.

Comment: Thank you but `LEFT JOIN imagetag` didn't also work. In other words I had 3 `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: While that was not the answer, +1 because I didn't care about its importance at all. Now I should work more on it. Thank you anyway :)