# Left Join don't list multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have problem listing multiple rows from two tables.
I had make research but I didn't find solution that fit my needs.
[Multiple use of LEFT JOIN brings only 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393872/multiple-use-of-left-join-brings-only-1-row) this is problem similar to mine. [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) also did not help me :)

This is what I have and what I want.
I have two table, for example; Products and Amounts.

```
product -> id - name
amount  -> id - pid - color - amount

product -> 1  - Book
           2  - Door
           3  - Table
amount  -> 1  - 1 - red - 5
           2  - 1 - blue- 10
           3  - 3 - green - 3
```

This is query I run with no problem:

```
SELECT product.id AS pid, 
product.name AS pname, 
sum(amount.amount) AS amnt 
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN amount ON product.id=amount.pid 
WHERE product.id='1'
```

And this is query I had problem with:

```
SELECT product.id AS pid, 
product.name AS pname, 
sum(amount.amount) AS amnt 
FROM product LEFT JOIN amount ON product.id=amount.pid 
WHERE product.name LIKE '%o%'
```

The second query list only one row, but I expect this result:

```
row1: 1 - Book - 15
row2: 2 - Door - null
```

Comment: I'm sure questions on SO used to be more interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using group by as :

```
SELECT product.id AS pid, product.name AS pname, sum(amount.amount) AS amnt FROM product LEFT JOIN amount ON product.id=amount.pid WHERE product.name LIKE '%o%' GROUP BY product.id
```

reason: Since sum() is an aggregate function it needs to know what elements to sum up for you. otherwise it will sum all up into one value (which you got).

See [group by modifiers in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html) about details.

Comment: I will try it immediately.